# auto change div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a div auto hide and show other div like changer. It does not work when I use multi div inside the main div:

```
<div id="div1">
```

What actually happens is that it hides all content of the inside div(s)
Is there any way to keep my div(s) for save my style and make an auto changer for my div(s)?

**html code**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='div1' class='display' style="background-color: red;"> 
        <div id="mydiv" style=" left:200; width:100; background-color:#F605C6;">
            <div id="main_adv" class="a" style="position:absolute;text-align:left;width:673px;height:256px">
                <div id="Layer3" class="a" style="position:absolute;text-align:left;left:176px;top:56px;width:490px;height:171px" title=""></div>
                <div id="img_adv" class="a" style="position:absolute;text-align:left;left:4px;top:55px;width:169px;height:172px;" title="">
                    <img id="ri" class="a" src="thumbs/img1.png" />
                </div>
                <div id="title_adv" class="a" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;left:4px;top:6px;width:662px;height:40px;" title="">
                    <div style="position:absolute;text-align:right;right:6px;top:4px;">
                        <span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:29px;right:5px">some text</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='div2' class='display' style="background-color: green;"> 
    div2
</div>

<div id='div3' class='display' style="background-color: blue;"> 
    div3
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$('html').addClass('js');

$(function() {
    var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 400);
    var counter = 0;

    function showDiv() {
        if (counter == 0) { counter++; return; }

        $('div','#container')
            .stop()
            .hide()
            .filter( function() { return this.id.match('div' + counter); })   
            .show('fast');

        counter == 16? counter = 0 : counter++; 
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to swap between `#div1, #div2, #div3` while keeping `#mydiv` in front all the time (doesnt change) ? Or do you want just to swap `#div1, #div2, #div3` that have different content?

Comment: Or do you just want to swap the styles (red, blue, green) ?

Comment: want just to swap #div1, #div2, #div3 that have different content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some basic code that changes divs continiously like you asked :

[jsfiddle.net/5jhuK/](http://jsfiddle.net/5jhuK/)

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='div1' class='display' style="background-color: red;">div1</div>
    <div id='div2' class='display' style="background-color: green;">div2</div>
    <div id='div3' class='display' style="background-color: blue;">div3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.display {
    display: none;
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var activeDiv = 1;
    showDiv(activeDiv); // show first one because all are hidden by default
    var timer = setInterval(changeDiv, 2000);

    function changeDiv() {
        activeDiv++;
        if (activeDiv == 4) {
            activeDiv = 1;
        }
        showDiv(activeDiv);
    }

    function showDiv(num) {
        $('div.display').hide(); // hide all
        $('#div' + num).fadeIn(); // show active
    }

});
```

It's really not complicated, next time when you ask something try to be concise and remove unnecessary code (like #mydiv)

Answer (score 0):

a few things:
1. html ids are unique, so you can just do something like below:
2. your code was missing a # in the find (e.g. "#div"+counter)
3. you can use the child selector ">" to just target divs one level down

```
var counter=1;
function showDiv() {


    $('#container > div').hide()
    $("#div"+counter).show();

    counter == 3? counter = 1 : counter++; 

  }
```

Comment: when it reach the last div it stop
how can to let it work continuously without stop

Comment: oh sorry about that, i just replied with a subset of your code.  if you just replace the showDiv() function in your original post it will loop.